# How to simulate more than 1 request(i.e. 4000 or more) on a single page to test performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Suppose I have a page called mysql_query_performance.php which contains code to select some records from table and echo it.

But I want to know how can I simulate more than 1 request to test the performance of that query?

**Is this Possible? If yes, How?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simple load testing, you might want to try [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). It's most likely already installed on your system.

```
ab -n 4000 -c 10 http://www.yoursite.com/mysql_query_performance.php
```

That's for 4000 requests performed 10 at a time (concurrently)

Comment: Thank you, This works best without any other software download

And ah! Thanks to all, they also right

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use [Siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/)

> Siege is a regression test and benchmark utility. It can stress test a single URL with a user defined number of simulated users, or it can read many URLs into memory and stress them simultaneously. The program reports the total number of hits recorded, bytes transferred, response time, concurrency, and return status. Siege supports HTTP/1.0 and 1.1 protocols, GET and POST directives, cookies, transaction logging, and basic authentication. Its features are configurable on a per user basis.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Pylot:

http://www.pylot.org/